# Клиент автоматически отключается

Tags: ubuntu, сокет

Доброго времени суток. Пишу обычный чат.

```
void server::start(){
    int MasterSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(_port_number);
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

bind(MasterSocket, (struct sockaddr*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
set_nonblock(MasterSocket);
listen(MasterSocket, SOMAXCONN);

int EPoll = epoll_create1(0);

struct epoll_event Event;
Event.data.fd = MasterSocket;
Event.events = EPOLLIN;
epoll_ctl(EPoll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, MasterSocket, &Event);

unique_lock<mutex> buffer_lock(m_buffer, defer_lock);
thread t(&server::algo_start, this);
t.detach();

while(true){
    struct epoll_event Events[_max_events];
    int N = epoll_wait(EPoll, Events, _max_events, -1);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(Events[i].data.fd == MasterSocket){
            sockaddr_in client_addr;
            int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
            int SlaveSocket = accept(MasterSocket, (struct sockaddr*)(&client_addr), (socklen_t*)client_addr_size);
            //int SlaveSocket = accept(MasterSocket, 0, 0);

            set_nonblock(SlaveSocket);
            SlaveSockets.insert(SlaveSocket);
            struct epoll_event Event;
            Event.data.fd = SlaveSocket;
            Event.events = EPOLLIN;
            epoll_ctl(EPoll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, SlaveSocket, &Event);
            cout << "New client connect..." << endl;
        }
        else{
            char buffer[1024];
            int RecvSize = recv(Events[i].data.fd, buffer, 1024, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
            if(RecvSize == 0 && errno != EAGAIN){
                shutdown(Events[i].data.fd, SHUT_RDWR);
                SlaveSockets.erase(Events[i].data.fd);
                epoll_ctl(EPoll, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, Events[i].data.fd, (epoll_event*)EPOLLIN);
                cout << "Client disconnect..." << endl;
            }
            if(RecvSize > 0){
                for(auto it = SlaveSockets.begin(); it != SlaveSockets.end(); it++)
                    if(*it != Events[i].data.fd)
                        send(*it, buffer, RecvSize, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
                buffer_lock.lock();
                message_buffer.push(message_info(RecvSize, buffer, 0));
                buffer_lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Проблема в определении SlaveSocket. Когда я вызываю accept(Master, 0, 0) - всё хорошо. Если я вызываю accept(Master, sockaddr, socklen), то мой клиент подключается и сразу же отключается (connection closed by foreign host). Почему так???

Answer (score -1):

тип данных `client_addr_size` нужно было поменять на `socklen_t`